# MATLAB converting efficiently a matrix into a formated cell string

Tags: matlab

I want to convert very large matrixes into formated cells string. I've created the following code, however it is very slow and I would like to improve it as much as possible.

```
tic
r = rand(1000,1000);
p = rand(1000,1000);

a = cellstr(num2str(r(:),'%+.2f'));
a = strrep(a,'+',' ');
a = strrep(a,'0.','.');
a = strcat(a(:),{'  '});
idx_05 = find(p<.05);
idx_01 = find(p<.01);
a(idx_05) = strrep(a(idx_05),'  ','* ');
a(idx_01) = strrep(a(idx_01),'* ','**');
a = reshape(a,size(r));
toc
```

> Elapsed time is 9.968568 seconds.

Comment: The profiler says most of the time is spent in the `strcat` command, so try to look in that direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the problem seems to be located in the `strcat`-command, we can find an alternative to achieve the same result. The `strrep`-command seems to execute quite fast, so let's use it once more.

Put some extra characters in your format-string used by `num2str`. After replace them with the spaces. This way we don't need `strcat`.

```
a = cellstr(num2str(r(:),'%+.2fAA'));
a = strrep(a,'AA','  ');
```

*Here are my timings:*
*<sup>mean of 10 measurements per method (i5, 2.5GHz)</sup>*

```
11.41s  ->  OP's code
 5.07s  ->  proposed solution
```

This equals an improvement of approximately **44.4**%.

Comment: That's a nice trick. Would it be possible to add the 2 blank spaces directly using the num2str function? why num2str(r(:),'%+.2f  ')) doesn't work?

Comment: @mat Trailing and leading spaces are trimmed using `num2str`. This even when entered in ASCII-representation with `\x20`.